# How to test a flutter app on my iPhone using codemagic.io

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, cicd

I used codemagic.io to build a flutter application and I downloaded the Runner.app.zip file. I can't seem to find a way to test it on my iPhone running iOS 14.4